# Angular - Navigating to route with result of observable

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, observable, subscribe

I have an interesting issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I am making a HTTP request which is returning an Observable.  I am subscribing to the observable and using the value as a parameter to my route when calling router.navigate.  The navigation works correctly but when I land on the new route I can't click anything, the page is completely locked.  As soon as I refresh the page everything works as expected.

Code snippet below for reference.

```
createTemplate() {
    this.templateService.create(this.templateModel)
        .subscribe(template => {
          this.router.navigate(['/admin/templates/builder', template.id]);
      });
    }
```

Comment: do you see the value of  `;template.id` in the url?

Comment: Yes, the value is passed correctly and `ngOnInit` is called correctly as the passed ID is used to retrieve the item using the API.

Comment: What does the landing page look like? Can you post some code for it?

Comment: This issue only manifests when creating a new item and navigating to the route, and after a refresh the page works as normal.  I can only assume it is something to do with the resolution of the observable and the navigation together.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No console errors, anything straightforward like console errors I have already checked

Answer (score -1):

What `this.templateService.create` method does? What kind of Observable returns?

Maybe you have to close the subscription?

```
createTemplate() {
    this.templateService.create(this.templateModel)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(template => {
          this.router.navigate(['/admin/templates/builder', template.id]);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Could you respond to the questions?

Comment: Yes I can respond to the questions, but only when I am online.

`templateService.create` returns `Observable<Template>`